# how to get http request without using XHR object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http

Is it possible to get information from URL without using the XmlHttpRequest .

I am trying to get document from my noSqlDatabase from URL 
 by the XHR object and It did not work . **but** If I type the URL in the browser I get the data.

Comment: what types of information you mean? from URL you can get the host name and such thing without using XmlHttpRequest. Please explain more.

Comment: what information you are looking for?

Comment: you can insert/delete/view your data in  mongolab (no-sql database) by  using URL that describes the operation that you want to execute .
https://support.mongolab.com/entries/20433053-rest-api-for-mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by 'get information' you mean load data from a 3rd party url without using XHR requests, the answer is yes, but with caveats.

One commonly used method to load json data cross-domain is called jsonp. Essentially, you define a function on your page:

```
var x = function(data){ //do something with data }
```

Then you create a script tag and append it to you page where the src attribute points to some other url that returns a js file like this:

```
x({ param: 'some data' });
```

The x function then executes on your page and has access to the 'param' data in the object. You can also pass a string or number using this method.

There is another method involving iframes and the window.name property of the iframe. This technique is a bit older but still works, but I won't go into a lot of detail about it here.  You can read more about it here, http://skysanders.net/subtext/archive/2010/10/11/leveraging-window.name-transport-for-secure-and-efficient-cross-domain-communications.aspx, and other places.